# Zend Http Client Reponse header data?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, http-headers, zend-http-client

I get json file content using the zend http client in magento.
I don't need header info on getBody(). I did test it on some host where it works. But the live host gives me troubles.

```
$request_url = "link";
$httpClientConfig = array('maxredirects' => 0);
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($request_url, $httpClientConfig);
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
try {
    $response = $client->request();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::throwException($this->__('Gateway request error: %s', $e->getMessage()));
}

Mage::log($response->getBody());
```

Result logging:

> ```
> 2015-01-08T09:12:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 761
> Connection: close
> Date: Mon, 05 Jan 2015 22:53:40 GMT
> Last-Modified: Sat, 15 Nov 2014 10:14:17 GMT
> ETag: "a8b17a42b7ef7e5960f9bd325a8c1892"
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> Server: AmazonS3
> Age: 5574
> X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
> Via: 1.1 522dd06c4c8acf822ccbebe21aee8d1c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
> X-Amz-Cf-Id: c6K9QJnOESg1NERKjG-v2fX_9eskmCzz_KUYdXrOb2NSjVTbWZ_x8Q==
> {
>   "assets": {
>     "standard": {
>       "url": "https://d3k1w8lx8mqizo.cloudfront.net/standard.png",
>     "infobox": {
>         "page1": "https://d3k1w8lx8mqizo.cloudfront.net/frontside.png",
>         "page2": "https://d3k1w8lx8mqizo.cloudfront.net/backside.png"
>       }
>     },
>     "promotion": {
>       "infobox": {
>         "page1": "https://d3k1w8lx8mqizo.cloudfront.net/frontside.png",
>         "page2": "https://d3k1w8lx8mqizo.cloudfront.net/backside.png"
>       },
>       "url": "https://d3k1w8lx8mqizo.cloudfront.net/standard.png",
>     "interest_free_months": 6,
>     "transaction_limit_min": 240.0
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($response->getBody());
```

Or don't retrieve the headers in the request when instantiating the Zend_Http_Client:

```
$httpClientConfig = array(
    'maxredirects' => 0, 
    'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_HEADER => false),
);
```

If the above doesn't work, you can try an alternative way of doing the request such as file_get_contents:

```
$response = file_get_contents($request_url);
```

I hope it helps.